# Using sendmail from bash script for multiple recipients

Tags: bash, sendmail

I'm running a bash script in cron to send mail to multiple recipients when a certain condition is met.

I've coded the variables like this:

```
subject="Subject"
from="user@example.com"
recipients="user1@mail.example user2@mail.example"
mail="subject:$subject\nfrom:$from\nExample Message"
```

And the actual sending:

```
echo -e $mail | /usr/sbin/sendmail "$recipients"
```

The problem is that only `user2@mail.example` is receiving the email. How can I change this so all the recipients receive the email?

NOTE: The solution has to be with sendmail, I'm using jailshell and it seems to be the only available method

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
recipients="user1@mail.example,user2@mail.example,user3@mail.example"
```

And another approach, using shell *here-doc*:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail "$recipients" <<EOF
subject:$subject
from:$from

Example Message
EOF
```

Be sure to separate the headers from the body with a blank line as per [RFC 822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt).

Answer (score 10):

Use option -t for sendmail.

in your case - `echo -e $mail | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t`
and add your recipient list to message itself like `To: someone@example.com someother@nowhere.example` right after the line `From:.....`

`-t` option means -
Read message for recipients. To:, Cc:, and Bcc: lines will be scanned for recipient addresses. The Bcc: line will be deleted before transmission.

Comment: When I pass the `-t` option, I get `sendmail: recipients with -t option not supported`. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

to use sendmail from the shell script

```
subject="mail subject"
body="Hello World"
from="me@example.com"
to="recipient1@example.com,recipient2@example.com"
echo -e "Subject:${subject}\n${body}" | sendmail -f "${from}" -t "${to}"
```

Answer (score 0):

For postfix `sendmail`, I am adding one line command useful for scripting

I had problem adding recipients in default position in the end of sendmail command in RHEL (Undisclosed Recipients) and piping echo command saved the day.

Option `-f` found from http://www.postfix.org/sendmail.1.html

Please note that syntax in echo is important, try echo to a file to check before attempting with sendmail.

`echo -e "To:receiver1@domain1, receiver2@domain2 \nSubject:Subject of email \n\nBody of email.\n" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -f sender@domain -F sendername -it`