# how to send a mail with a message in unix script

Tags: linux, email, unix, ksh

New to unix and learning the talk and walk of it.
I am writing a script in .ksh and have a requirement of sending a mail with a message.
Currently using this command in my script:

```
    mailx -s"File not found" abc@def.com
```

This command helps me having a subject and the recipient name.
My question is how can I write a message along with it. Cause every time i run the script it pauses and asks me to enter the message and then executes, I want to pre-include the message so the script would not pause in between.

Answer (score 8):

```
echo 'Message body goes here' | mail -s 'subject line goes here' email@provider.com
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this on the command line or inside a script:

```
echo "This is the message." | mailx -s "Subject" abc@def.com
```

You can use pre-defined messages from files:

```
cat message.txt | mailx -s "Subject" abc@def.com
```

Comment: The 1st one works for me, but when i receive my mail the message body has "<end>" as trialing which doesn't get displayed in mail but when i receive it you get a preview on your taskbar right its there i can see it doesn't make a difference but was curious to know    Thanks alot for the help

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively to mailx (mentioned in the other answers) you can also use sendmail:

```
cat <<EOF | sendmail -t
To: recipients-mailaddress
From: your-mailaddress
Subject: the-subject
mailtext
blabla
.
EOF
```

Perhaps you need to add the full path to sendmail if it's not in your path. E.g. /usr/sbin/sendmail or /usr/lib/sendmail.

**Update**:
See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390894/using-sendmail-from-bash-script-for-multiple-recipients)

Answer (score 2):

as mailx takes the body as input on stdin you can pipe the body to it:

```
echo "Hello World" | mailx -s"File not found" abc@def.com
```

Or use a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)

```
mailx -s"File not found" abc@def.com << END_TEXT
Hello World 
END_TEXT
```

Comment: The second looks trendy, i tried it but doesn't work for me :(

Comment: For the 1st command i used the following:                                  mail_person=abc@def.com                                                 echo "test"|mailx -s"test" $mail_person                                   now this command does mail me the message but also adds it in /var/spool/mail in unix

Answer (score 1):

Define the mailcontent beforehand and do it like this:

```
mailx -s"File not found" abc@def.com < mailcontent
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to add attachment to the you want to send. Here you go:

```
echo 'Type Message body' | mailx -s 'Type subject' -a path/filename.txt email@provider.com
```

> EXAMPLE:

```
echo 'PFA report' | mailx -s 'Today's Report' -a `path`/report1306.txt  xyz@gmail.com
```