# Send mail Using Shell Script | Error | No response

Tags: linux, shell, unix, mailing

I tried a couple of methods to send a report mail from my shell script. It either gives me an error or I do not get any mail. Please find it below.

```
echo "My Mail" | mail -s "My Subject" achintxxxxx@gmail.com
```

Following gives me the error:

> mail: illegal option -- s
>   usage: mail [+] [-epqr] [-f file]
>          mail [-dt] persons

and if I use the below command

```
echo "My Mail" | mailx -s "My Subject" achintxxxxx@gmail.com
```

It does not give me any error, but I would not receive any mail at achintxxxxx@gmail.com(or any other mail ID)

Would anyone help me out here??

Comment: Edit: Masked your email id. Please avoid putting your real email address/information in future.

Comment: Have you configured your smtp? `mailq`?

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426077/how-to-send-a-mail-with-a-message-in-unix-script)?