# How to make the contact form submit responses to email?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I want to make the contact form to submit the responses when the user hits the `submit` button. Upon the user hitting the `submit` button, it should also redirect them to `thankyou.html`, which I have already accomplished. But the responses should be emailed to me as well. I am stuck on that part and cannot figure it out in the PHP file.

### PHP file

```
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'm.hussainomer03@gmail.com'; // Put Your email address here.
if (empty($_POST['name']) ||
    empty($_POST['email']) ||
    empty($_POST['message'])) {
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
if (!preg_match(
    "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i",
    $email_address)) {
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if (empty($errors)) {
    $to = $myemail;
    $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. " .
        " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n " .
        "Email: $email_address\n Message \n $message";
    $headers = "From: $myemail\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
    mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
    
    // Redirect to the 'thank you' page.
    header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
}
```

### Rest of the code

```css
input[type=text], [type=email], select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: rgb(62, 3, 179);
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: deeppink;
}

.contactform {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-top: 1%;
    width: 100%;
    animation-name: gradient;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.contactform:hover {
    animation-name: gradient;
    animation-duration: 15s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


.column {
    float: center;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 6px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 40%;

}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column, input[type=submit] {
        width: auto;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="contactform">
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h2><br/>Get In Touch</h2>
        </div>
        <p>Feel Free To Reach Out To Me Through This Form! </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <form name="myform" action="contact.php" method="POST">
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." required>

            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.." required>

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required>

            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Lets Collaborate..." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I tried to rename the classes/objects in the `php` file before, but that did not do the trick either.

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail

Comment: Bro change the ```name="firstname"``` to ```name="name"```, ```name="subject"``` to ```name="message"``` and remove the lastname input field as it is not used in the php file

Comment: @HussainOmer does it work?

Comment: Nope it doesn't

Comment: @HussainOmer Can you print the result of `mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);`. What does it return?

Answer (score 3):

Change the `action="thankyou.html"` to `action="yourMail.php"`
so that the form POST data is sent to your php file containing the `mail()` function not to your thankyou.html.
Also note that you need an SMTP server to send mails from your localhost. I would recommend you to use PHPMailer.

### HTML

```
<form name="myform" action="contact.php" method="POST">
            <label for="name">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." required>

       <!--     <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.." required> -->

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required>

            <label for="message">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Lets Collaborate..." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
```

Comment: But like I said, I also need to redirect the user to thankyou.HTML along with the responses being sent to my email.

Comment: action tag is used to specify where to send the form data and not where to redirect after submitting. The ```header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');``` in your .php file which after sending the mail will redirect to contact-form-thank-you.html.

Comment: are you executing this on a local system?

Comment: Ok so in `repl.it` there are two options to choose to write code in: `HTML/CSS/JS` and `PHP` but is there no way I can use the PHP in the `HTML/CSS/JS` Server because that's where my website is on

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the above answer, you should be changing the form POST action to your `mailTo.php` file as it will send the mail. After that you can do is on the success of your mail sent, you can redirect to `thankYou.html` through PHP server, and on failing you can stay on the same page, show respective errors found/occurred.
So it will be,

```
# on success
header('Location: http://your-website/contact-form-thank-you.html');
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `action="thankyou.html"` to `action="yourMail.php"` so the form data will be sent to PHP file containing `mail()` function.

```
<form name="myform" action="contact.php" method="POST">
            <label for="name">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." required>

       <!--     <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.." required> -->

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required>

            <label for="message">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Lets Collaborate..." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
```

Maybe this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

hello i wrote the code bellow and edited it if it didn't worked or you faced any problems let me know in the comments i hope you find this answer helpful
html page :

```
<form name="myform" action="contact.php" method="POST">
 <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
 <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." required>

 <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
 <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.." required>

 <label for="email">Email:</label>
 <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required>

 <label for="subject">Subject</label>
 <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Lets Collaborate..." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

php page :

```
$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['subject'];
if(empty($fname) || 
empty($lname) || 
empty($email_address) || 
empty($message)){
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}else{
//some other code 
$to = $myemail;
$email_subject = "Contact form submission:" . $name;
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
" Here are the details:\n Name: " . $name . "\n ".
"Email: $email_address\n Message \n " . $message;
$headers = "From:" . $myemail . "\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To:" . $email_address;
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

header('Location: thank-you.html');
}
```

Comment: you should explain why or how your solution fixes the issue. it will be really useful for others to understand.

Comment: our friends wrote $_POST values wrongly and some of mail function content wrongly also so when the post name doesn't match the posted values it will not work

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you already accomplished redirecting to `thankyou.html`, but the email is not being sent to you.
The issue might lie with `mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);`.

You see, `mail` doesn't really send the mail by itself, rather it invokes `sendmail` in the host, which in turn queues the message to be sent through the local exchange. So

- PHP may fail to invoke `sendmail` (in this case, `mail` should return false)
- `sendmail` may fail (to check try https://stackoverflow.com/a/13390926/1626321)
- in many cases, your hosting may have a dummy `sendmail`
- your email may be blocked/discarded by the exchange (mark it as spam/suspicious, many hosting also block mail to promote their own email product)

The best solution is to switch to using SMTP, using something like `PHPMailer` (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). There should be plenty of tutorials out there on how to use it. You can use SMTP server from your hosting or maybe even use Gmail.

##### More comprehensive answer can be found here by [@John Conde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/250259/john-conde) https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/1626321

Answer (score 0):

```
     <section id="contact">
        <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
            <div class="contactform">
                <div style="text-align:center">
                    <div class="section-title">
                        <h2><br/>Get In Touch</h2>
                    </div>
                    <p>Feel Free To Reach Out To Me Through This Form! </p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column">
                        <form name="myform" action="mailto:youraddr@domain.tld" method="POST">
                        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." required>

                        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.." required>

                        <label for="email">Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required>

                        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                        <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Lets Collaborate..." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

In HTML you can specify a mailto: address in the  element's [action] attribute.
What this will do is allow the user's email client to create an email prepopulated with the fields in the .